# Drawing a PolyLineSegment incrementally creates visual artifacts

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I have a sample app that reads audio data from a file and renders a stereo waveform.

Since the reading of audio data takes some time, I decided to do the rendering incrementally. As the data becomes available, additional points are added to the waveform.

Such rendering however creates a nasty looking "trumpet" artifact, as seen on the screenshot.

[image]

This code snippet illustrates how the PolylineSegment instances are set up:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
var leftWaveformPolyLine = new PolyLineSegment();
var rightWaveformPolyLine = new PolyLineSegment();
Point StartPoint() => new Point(_waveformDimensions.LeftMargin(), centerHeight);
_leftPath.Data = new PathGeometry(new[] { new PathFigure(StartPoint(), new[] { leftWaveformPolyLine }, false) });
_rightPath.Data = new PathGeometry(new[] { new PathFigure(StartPoint(), new[] { rightWaveformPolyLine }, false) });
```

This code snippet illustrates the consuming side and is called from within a WPF custom control:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
var observable = Tune.WaveformStream(); // this is an instance of IObservable<float>
_waveformBuildDisposable = observable.ObserveOn(_uiContext) // UI context since we need to draw     on the UI thread
    .Buffer(20) // take 20 floats at a time
    .Subscribe(
        renderWaveform.DrawWfPointByPoint, // this one does the drawing
        renderWaveform.CompleteWaveform); // this is called when we're done
Task.Run(() => observable.Waveform(8000)); // the method "Waveform" does the actual analysis of the audio data and provides the stream of floats consumed above, the parameter "8000" is a "resolution" and is not important here.
```

The producer is a generator method that yields the floats as it analyzes them. It's decorated in a reactive class that calls the `onNext(float value)` method of each consumer.

The actual rendering happens thusly:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
var height = _mainCanvas.RenderSize.Height / 2.0d;
var location = ((_pointsDrawn / 2) * _pointThickness) + _waveformDimensions.LeftMargin(); // where to draw - increasing by the point thickness
_leftWaveformPolyLine.Points.Add(new Point(_xLocation, _centerHeight - left * height)); // this adds a point to the left channel
_rightWaveformPolyLine.Points.Add(new Point(_xLocation, _centerHeight + right * height)); // this adds a point to the right channel
```

I would love to figure out what causes the visual artifact and what steps I could take to remove it.

Comment: It simply looks like the centre of the poly line is being drawn more and more off centre as the stream is read, but we are missing quite a bit of code so can only speculate at the moment. Are you sure that at no point the centre of the line is shifting due to some error in calculation? I assume all floats are positive values? If so, why is some of the polyline rendering negatively?

Comment: It does not look that way because when the data is available up-front, the PolyLine is filled up instantly and no visual artifact appears.